# Meteor: Stripe incorrect security code doesn't throw client error

Tags: javascript, meteor, stripe-payments

I'm doing some tests and just caught an error in my site. I collect the users payment information but I don't charge them. This gives them access to a free trial.

The problem is that the response from meteor (on client) is a nice 200 OK, and it doesn't throw any errors. But on the client side I do get an error and the customer doesn't get saved. So with this meteor accepts the 'payment' and creates the account even though no payment info was saved.

Has anyone run into this? Anyone could let me know how to fix it would be appreciated!

This is client side code:

```
Stripe.card.createToken({
    number: cardNumber,
    cvc: secCode,
    exp_month: expMonth,
    exp_year: expYear
}, function(status, response) {
  console.log(status, response);
    if (response.error){
      alert(response.error.message);
      throw error
    }
    else {
      stripeToken = response.id;
      createTheUser(stripeToken);
    }
});
```

Server side error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Your card's security code is incorrect.
```

Comment: did you set both your stripe publishable key on the client and stripe secret key on the server?

Answer (score 1):

When you create the token with the [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) `Stripe.card.createToken()` function, Stripe doesn't check the card against the bank networks. It only checks that the card details aren't blatantly invalid (correct number of digits, expiration date in the future, etc.).

It is only when you use the token to [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) or a [customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) that the card will actually be checked and possibly [raise an error](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#errors).

One way to avoid that is to use [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) instead of your own Stripe.js form. Checkout will run a $0/$1 authorization on the card and will not return a token if the authorization fails.